# VS CodeのRemote-SSHで発生したエラーの対処がわかりません

Tags: vscode

VS CodeでRemote-SSHの設定をしたのですが，下記のエラーが発生し，Remote-SSHのCONNECTIONSに接続先が表示されません．
ただ，コマンドパレットの`Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...`からでは，`~/.ssh/config`で設定した接続先Host名が表示され，無事ログインできます．

対処方法が不明なので，遭遇した方，対処法がわかる方ご教授よろしくお願いいたします．

```
command 'opensshremotesexplorer.configure' not found

command 'opensshremotesexplorer.refresh' not found
```

Comment: 次のバグのようですが、お使いのVS CodeのバージョンとOSは何でしょうか。 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/621

Comment: @Roger Sanghee Gold VS Codeのバージョンは1.36.1で，OSはmacOS Sierraバージョン10.12.6です．

Comment: 修正版はまだ、`Code-insider`でないとないかもしれませんが、`Ctrl + Shift + p`で`Remote-SSH: Settings`を入力してssh.confを指定してみたらどうでしょうか。